# ArrayAccess by string on an unknown or dynamic type

Tags: abstract, haxe

I've built my own Yaml Parser using a couple of more advanced stuff like abstracts in haxe in order to better understand how everything works, and I've hit yet another wall.

The important part is an abstract, `abstract YamlMap (StringMap<Either<String, YamlMap>>)`, which acts as a container for my data. A "node" can either be a string or another yamlmap, deeper into the tree.

This `YamlMap` has multiple methods to get data, like `getMap(key):YamlMap` and `getString(key):String`, and a dynamic access one, `getDynamic(key):Dynamic`.

Unfortunately, it seems that only one `@:arrayAccess` will work be abstract or I'm missing something. It also seems that you cannot "arrayAccess" a dynamic object with strings, or at least the compiler is preventing me from doing it.

So, this works: `data.getMap('test_node').getMap('sub_node1').getString('value2')`
But this doesn't: `data['test_node']['sub_node2']['value2']`

If I set `getDynamic` as arrayAccess, it tells me `sub_node2` should be an int. But if I set both `getMap` and `getString` as arrayAccess, it'll always ever call the first arrayAccess-labeled method. So it either fails when trying to get "value" (which is a string but the code attempts to get a map) or doesn't compile because, I'm guessing, it's trying to access a character from a string and not a map position.

So, my guess here is, related to this [manual entry](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-array-access.html), that arrayAccess on anything not abstract is locked to an int, thus the dynamic object refuses to be accessed with a string.

A possible solution I can think of is to, instead of using a dynamic value, to return some kind of abstract that will "flatten" to the correct type upon casting. Would there be any other methods of achieving stringified array access on a dynamic map?

Note: This is, in a way, out of curiosity as the current method with different calls for maps and strings works well enough for everyday use. I also know of the existing yaml haxelib but this is as much a learning experience as it is an attempt to replace the haxelib which can sometimes be buggy.

Here's a [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/sm9f3Vq2) of the YamlMap abstract for anyone interested.

Comment: Regarding your `@:arrayAccess` problem, it looks like you can only have one per parameter type (ignoring return type.) All of your accessors operate on a `String` parameter, so they collide. In general, yes, making "dynamic string-accessed objects" is tricky. Your return type must be the abstract itself to be able to chain the accessors (e.g. `obj['a']['b']`), but then how do you know when you're at a leaf? I've tried the same to code up a JS-like Object. In my experience, it never really works how I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, an abstract *can* have multiple `@:arrayAccess` methods:

```
abstract MultiArrayAccess({}) from {} {
    public function new() this = {};
    @:arrayAccess function getInt(i:Int) return i;
    @:arrayAccess function getString(s:String) return Std.parseInt(s);
}
```

```
var i = new MultiArrayAccess();
trace(i[1]); // 1
trace(i["3"]); // 3
```

The difference between this an your example is that the **key types are different**. This is necessary because array access on abstracts (and abstracts in general) are a *compile-time* feature. Here's what the AST dump for these two array accesses looks like:

```
_Main.MultiArrayAccess_Impl_.getInt(i, 1)
_Main.MultiArrayAccess_Impl_.getString(i, "3")
```

So, the compiler has to know which method to call *at compile-time*. This is impossible in your case, because the key types are `String` for both methods. By replacing both `getString()` and `getMap()` with `[]`, your are losing information.

---

> It also seems that you cannot "arrayAccess" a dynamic object with strings, or at least the compiler is preventing me from doing it.

That's correct, array access is not allowed on `Dynamic`. However, the standard library has an abstract called [`haxe.DynamicAccess`](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/DynamicAccess.html), which is an abstract that implements array access with `Reflect.field()`. Of course, that results in runtime overhead. You *could* have an implementation that's fully dynamic based on that:

```
typedef YamlMap = haxe.DynamicAccess<YamlMapValue>;

abstract YamlMapValue(YamlMap) from YamlMap {
    @:arrayAccess function get(key:String):YamlMapValue {
        return this.get(key);
    }

    @:arrayAccess function setMap(key:String, value:YamlMap) {
        Reflect.setField(this, key, value);
    }

    @:arrayAccess function setString(key:String, value:String) {
        Reflect.setField(this, key, value);
    }
}
```

```
var data = new YamlMap();
data["test_node"] = new YamlMap();
data["test_node"]["sub_node1"] = new YamlMap();
data["test_node"]["sub_node1"]["value2"] = "foo";

var map:YamlMapValue = data["test_node"]["sub_node1"];
trace(map["value2"]); // foo
```

However, this is not necessarily a good idea, since you lose a lot of type-safety (and as a result, performance) this way.

Comment: Thanks for the slick example, Jens. One issue I see, though, is that getting a string your string back out of it (at the leaf node) is difficult. e.g. `var s:String = data["test_node"]["sub_node1"]["value2"];` gives: `YamlMapValue should be String`. Playing with it here: https://try.haxe.org/#B83C7

Comment: Ok, @oli_chose123 here's a `toString` that may get you closer to what you want: https://try.haxe.org/#5F6c3 -- or even just `@:to function toString():String return untyped this;`

Comment: Thanks again for a great answer, and thanks @JeffWard for this addition. So there it is, it's one arrayAccess per accessor, not per return type. My bad. Instead of using too much reflection, then, I think I'll either use the array access on maps only (```map['node1']['node2'].getString('potato')```) or experiment on some kind of abstract accessor for strings. Technically, that would make it two different accessors at compile-time, no?

```getString(key:StringKey)```
```getMap(key:MapKey)```
```abstract StringKey(String)```